# how does mongo select primary shard in cluster?

Tags: mongodb

```
 i have created 3 mongod , 2 mongos and a single config server.
 While i look in to  sh.printShardingStatus(). 
 it says some node as primary one.
```

How does mongoDb select its primary shard to hold un shard collection and can i change primary one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The primary shard in a new cluster is always the first shard. See the [manual](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/sharded-cluster-shards/)

Comment: Can i change primary shard??

Comment: @Sidharthan Yes, but as mentioned in the link I put in the answer, it is an expensive operation.

Comment: more specifically it will always use the config servers to understand the layout of the cluster

Comment: This answer is incorrect. A cluster does not have a primary shard. The term primary shard only applies to a database.

Comment: @JasonR.Coombs that is an incredibly pedantic way to read the answer. Yes shards only applies to databases, but read the title of the question - do you think the person asking the question needed an education about database vs. cluster?!

Comment: I'm not trying to be pedantic, but I could have phrased my critique better. I'm here because I have the same question. Both the manual and this answer fail to answer the question, "How does MongoDB select the primary shard for a new database?" Your answer is "the first shard", but "first" isn't even well defined. Do you mean the first shard that was added to the cluster? Or the first one in the list of shards?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the movePrimary command. Details are here. It requires you to drain out the other shards before you can run this command.

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/movePrimary/

Comment: I wouldn't use movePrimary - it will leave your cluster in an inconsistent state.  After a movePrimary the mongoses will disagree about where the database data should be stored.  See http://jira.mongodb.org for the full set of bugs on movePrimary...

Answer (score 1):

According to [the manual](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/sharded-cluster-shards/#primary-shard), "Databases created [after the cluster is deployed] may reside on any shard in the cluster." When you create a database in a sharded cluster, it will be assigned a primary but the mechanism by which it selects that primary is not documented. I invite others to dig into [the source](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/tree/master/src/mongo/s) to track down and document the actual mechanism used.

In a Commercial Support ticket, MongoDB has confirmed that a new database will be assigned a primary on the "most available" shard where most available means the shard with the least amount of data on it.

Answer (score 1):

**Primary Shard**

Each database in a sharded cluster has a primary shard that holds all the un-sharded collections for that database. Each database has its own primary shard. The primary shard has no relation to the primary in a replica set.

The mongos selects the primary shard when creating a new database by picking the shard in the cluster that has the least amount of data. mongos uses the totalSize field returned by the listDatabase command as a part of the selection criteria.

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/core/sharded-cluster-shards/#primary-shard